# Capture tmap bounding box as a Shiny input

Tags: r, shiny, tmap

I have a Shiny app with tmap and want the user's zoom and pan to update the data filter.  For instance:

```
require(tmap)
require(shiny)
require(dplyr)

d = readr::read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/curran/13d30e855d48cdd6f22acdf0afe27286/raw/0635f14817ec634833bb904a47594cc2f5f9dbf8/worldcities_clean.csv') |> 
  group_by(lat = 3*round(lat/3), lng = 3*round(lng/3)) |> 
  summarise(n = length(lat), .groups = 'drop')

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  tmap_mode("view")
  
  output$map = renderTmap({
    
    # I want bbx to reflect the current leaflet bounding box
    bbx = list(top = 70, right = 60, bottom = 20, left = -20)
    
    p = d |> filter(lat > bbx$bottom, lat < bbx$top, lng > bbx$left, lng < bbx$right) |> 
      sf::st_as_sf(coords = c('lng', 'lat'), crs = 'WGS84')
    
    tm_basemap("Stamen.TonerLite") +
      tm_shape(p) +
      tm_symbols(size="n", col = 'n', border.col = 'white', # shape=15,
                 palette = c('navy','red'),
                 legend.size.show = FALSE, scale=1, id="key", popup.vars = TRUE)
  })
}

ui = mapUI = fluidPage(
  tmapOutput('map', width = '95vw', height = '95vh')
)

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(launch.browser = FALSE))
```

How can the `bbx` object capture the current leaflet bounding box?  `tmap` doesn't seem to offer anything that looks like event capture and I've not managed to pin down a client-side js method for this (or hack one myself) but presumably it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. If one can find a way how to do this in `leaflet` (the R package) or `mapview` I will include this in `tmap` v4

Comment: In leaflet there are map events here as explained here - https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html